# Xcode 10 not pushing using ssh

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I'm using Xcode 10.1. I have a repository on BitBucket and I use SSH keys push to the repository.

Everything is working fine if I push using terminal. When I try using Xcode to push, I receive the following message:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Same problem in XCode 11. Ridiculous.

Comment: Probably because Xcode adds ```-m PEM```
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647419/12188194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create a new key from Xcode and use that. I still have no idea why the key created from terminal using `ssh-keygen`. I tried using `ssh-key -t rsa`, it did not work either. The only time it actually works is when the SSH keys are generated from the Xcode.

I guess this is a bug.